# How to echo json object without being wrapped in quotes?

Tags: php, string, json

First time dealing with json. I have a php file that processes the post vars sent to it via ajax and then it will echo back a json_encoded array. I cannot iterate thru it because it's wrapped in double quotes. How I do get around this?

The jquery code:

```
$j.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://example.com/doaction.php',
   data: 'num=' + fileNum[1],
   success: function(jsonobj) {
     for (var key in jsonobj) {
       if (jsonobj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         var jsonob = jsonobj[key];
         console.log(key + " = " + jsonob);
       }
     }
   }
});
```

The php code in doaction.php:

```
if ($_GET['num']) {
    $meta = file_meta($_GET['num']); // returns an array
    echo json_encode($meta);
}
```

file_meta function:

```
function file_meta($num = 1) {
$num = '_' . $num;
$meta = array(
    'filename' . $num => array(
        'value' => ''),
    'link' . $num => array(
        'value' => ''),
    'description_' . $num => array(
        'value' => ''),
    'metadata' => array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'label' => 'Indicate applicable competencies:',
        'items' => array(
            'core_teaching' . $num => array(
                'label' => 'Core Teaching',
                'value' => 0
            ),
            'teaching_learning' . $num => array(
                'label' => 'Teaching Learning',
                'value' => 0
            ), 
            'instructional_design' . $num => array(
                'label' => 'Instructional Design',
                'value' => 0
            ), 
            'assignment_and_evaluation' . $num => array(
                'label' => 'Assignment & Evaluation',
                'value' => 0
            ),
            'research' . $num => array(
                'label' => 'Research',
                'value' => 0
            ),
            'mentoring' . $num => array(
                'label' => 'Mentoring',
                'value' => 0
            )   
        )
    )
);

return $meta;
```

}

The result in the console isn't what I was expecting. It should be in key-value pairs but it's gibberish instead like shown below.

```
 500 = ,
 501 = "
 502 = v
 503 = a
 .
 .
 .
```

I am pretty sure it's because the json object `$.ajax()` is getting is wrapped in quotes. When I assign the `object` without quotes directly to `jsonobj` I get the correct result. When I call file_meta() directly from within the `$.ajax()` function I get the correct result:

```
var jsonobj = <?php $etc = file_meta(); echo json_encode($etc); ?>;
// iterate here...
```

However that's not what I want because `file_meta()` needs to be passed with a value from an element retrieved on click event. And sending it via $_GET is the only I know.

Comment: Where can you not iterate through it? Javascript or PHP? Are you `json_decode()` ing it?

Comment: I don't see the problem in your code, where are the double quotes interrupting?

Comment: That's not an array but an object. Maybe that's your issue?

Comment: What does this file_meta() function do? and what's the gibberish you're getting? As well, unless your PHP script is outputting an appropriate header, jquery won't assume the response is JSON unless you tell give a `type: json` argument on the .get() call.

Comment: @Marc B: as the comment says, it just returns an array... By gibberish I mean it's not in key-value pairs as what you would expect in my code...

Comment: @hakre: yes it's a javascript object, I know...

Comment: @Marc B: you're right, adding `dataType: 'json'` fixes it.. Thanks! :D Now if you could pls add your comment as an answer so I can choose it as the correct solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the JSON string into a PHP variable

```
$var = json_decode('{"file":{"test": 0}}');
```

In javascript use:

```
var decoded = eval('{"file":{"test": 0}}');
```

If you are using the jQuery library use:

```
var json = '{"file":{"test": 0}}';
var decoded = $.parseJSON(json);
```

Comment: If you are using a real browser, you can also use `JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: @igorw: What is a real browser?